# Second-order nonlinear boundary value problem

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-value, boundary-condition-at-infinity, boundary-conditions

I am trying to follow [this work](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/pssb.2221860223), in which Eq. (11), the 2nd-order, nonlinear differential equation depends on a pair of parameters $ (\kappa, h) $. But now I only care about the case with a vanishing $ h $ and several values of $ \kappa $:

$$
\begin{align}
0&=\frac{\mathrm d^2\theta}{\mathrm d\varrho^2}+\frac{1}{\varrho}\frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\mathrm d\varrho}-\left(1+\frac{1}{\varrho^2}\right)\sin\theta\cos\theta+\frac{4\kappa}{\pi}\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\varrho}-h\sin\theta\\
\pi&=\theta(0)\\
0&=\theta(\infty)
\end{align}
$$

So I try

```
Clear[sol]
sol = Block[{eq, θ0, θ1, ϱ0, ϱ1, κlist},
            {θ0, θ1} = {0.99 π, 0.001};
            {ϱ0, ϱ1} = {0.01, 10};
            κlist = {.6, .7, .8, .9, .95};
            eq[κ_, h_] = θ''[ϱ] + 1/ϱ θ'[ϱ] - (1 + 1/ϱ^2) Sin[θ[ϱ]] Cos[θ[ϱ]] + (4 κ)/π Sin[θ[ϱ]]^2/ϱ - h Sin[θ[ϱ]] == 0 // Simplify;
            NDSolveValue[{eq[#, 0.], θ[ϱ0] == θ0, θ[ϱ1] == θ1}, θ[ϱ], ϱ, AccuracyGoal -> 20] & /@ κlist
           ]
```

Actually, above code works fine to give five `InterpolatingFunction`s. But the problem arises when I try to add a new value `0.5` to `κlist`. Can anyone help to get a reasonable solution for $ \kappa = 0.5 $?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a proper initial guess and choose a smaller `ϱ1` as approximation of $\infty$ helps:

```
sol = Block[{eq, θ0, θ1, ϱ0, ϱ1, κlist}, 
  {θ0, θ1} = {0.99 π, 0.001};
  {ϱ0, ϱ1} = {0.01, 5};
  κlist = {.5};
  eq[κ_, h_] = θ''[ϱ] + 1/ϱ θ'[ϱ] - (1 + 
        1/ϱ^2) Sin[θ[ϱ]] Cos[θ[ϱ]] + (4 κ)/π Sin[θ[ϱ]]^2/ϱ - h Sin[θ[ϱ]] == 0;
  NDSolveValue[{eq[#, 0.], θ[ϱ0] == θ0, θ[ϱ1] == θ1}, θ, ϱ, 
     Method -> {"Shooting", 
       "StartingInitialConditions" -> {θ[ϱ0] == (99 π)/100, θ'[ϱ0] == -10}}] & /@ κlist]

ListLinePlot[sol, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Please keep the method of finite difference.

Comment: Is there any thumb of rules for selection of approximation to $ \infty $?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ I removed the FDM approach because that result is incorrect. To fix the FDM solution, we also need to choose a smaller `ϱ1` and set proper initial guess i.e. the FDM approach doesn't show any advantage compared to the traditional shooting method approach in your case, that's the reason I decide not to re-add it to my post. As to approximation of $\infty$, a rule of thumb is, the approximation should be large enough but not too large.

Comment: OK, I see. There is some uncertainty in choosing approximation of $ \infty $. Why $ \kappa=0.5 $ fails my original code?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ As mentioned above, "the approximation should be large enough but not too large" is just a rule of thumb, and sadly I'm unable to give a in-depth explanation for why it works. BTW, `κlist = {.6, .7, .8, .9, .95};` all fails to converge to a reasonable result by default in _v9.0.1_ (I guess you're in _v11_, right? ) So this is somewhat related to the robustness of the solver.